# Angular 5 and atmosphere.js

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, atmosphere.js

I need to use atmosphere.js in my angular 5 project.

I've done these steps:

```
npm install --save @types/atmosphere.js
npm install --save atmosphere.js
```

and I've created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
import * as Atmosphere from 'atmosphere.js';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class  WebsocketService {
  public eventsSubject: Rx.Subject<any> = new Rx.Subject<any>();
  private url:string = "http://localhost:4200/ws/register";

  private socket: Atmosphere.Atmosphere;
  private subSocket: any;
  private request: Atmosphere.Request;

  public dataStream: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {

     ...

     try {
        this.subSocket = this.socket.subscribe(this.request);
     } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
     }
  }
```

but the socket is always undefined.

where is my error?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually instantiate your socket in someway, <strike>my guess is using `new`:</strike>

```
private socket: Atmosphere.Atmosphere = new Atmosphere.Atmosphere();
```

The first part is just a type definition you give to the `TypeScript` compiler. The property will stay undefined until you actually assign something to it.

Although looking over their [api](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/atmosphere.js-API), this does not seem to be the right way. Try this:

```
export class  WebsocketService {
  // ...
  private socket: typeof Atmosphere = Atmosphere;
  private subSocket: Subscription;
  private request: Atmosphere.Request = new atmosphere.AtmosphereRequest();

  constructor() {
     try {
        this.subSocket = this.socket.subscribe(this.request);
     } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
     }
  }
}
```